# undefined reference to `Base::Base(int, int)'

Tags: c++

I am making a small game, I want to use abstract classes to easily manage creating new entities.
Although I am having a problem with creating a constructor, I will show you my code:

`Base.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Base{
    public:
        Base(int x, int y);
        virtual ~Base() {}

        virtual void tick() = 0;
        virtual void render(sf::RenderWindow& g) = 0;
        virtual void setPos(int x, int y) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
        virtual void setDimensions(int width, int height) { this->width = width; this->height = height; }
    private:
        int x, y, width, height = 0;
        float velX, velY = 0;
};
```

---

`Derive.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "Base.h"

class Derive: public Base {
    public:
        Derive(int x, int y);
        ~Derive() {}
        void tick() override;
        void render(sf::RenderWindow& g) override;
    private:
        int x, y, width, height = 0;
        float velX, velY = 0;

};
```

---

`Derive.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "headers/Derive.h"

Derive::Derive(int x, int y) : Base(x, y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->width = 32;
    this->height = 32;
    this->velX = 0;
    this->velY = 0;
}

void Derive::tick() {

}

void Derive::render(sf::RenderWindow& g) {

}
```

---

Now, I am getting an error in the `Derive.cpp` file:

`undefined reference to 'Base::Base(int, int)'`

I have been searching around for alot of time and cannot find anything that works, now this maybe due to me only just starting recently, but I specifically decided to learn about games because I like Object Oriented Programming.

If there are things I should do differently please tell me as I have recently started learning C++ and the more I know, the better.

---

Somebody asked for my `main` file but it is split apart, I will only show the relevant code:

`Game.cpp`

```
Game::Game() {
    this->player = new Player(0,0);
}
```

---

`Main.cpp`

```
#include "headers/main.h"
#include "headers/game.h"

int Main::main() {
    Game game;
    game.run();
    return 0;
}
```

The `game.run();` refers to the game loop, so that is not needed.

Comment: Where is your definition for `Base::Base(int, int)`? It's nowhere in the code you have shown us. (You have provided a definition for `Derive::Derive(int x, int y)` - you have to do the same for the `Base` constructor.)

Comment: `Base(int x, int y);` is not a definition. It's a declaration. You need some dive bombing seagulls in there: `Base(int x, int y) {this->x = y; this->y = x;}` (or maybe `this->x = x;` if you want to be boring)

Comment: @AdrianMole, ah ok, I didn't know I had to do that, I am just learning C++ from coming over from Java, I will see now if that changes anything.

Comment: Suggestion: 1) `virtual ~Base() = default;` 2) Don't define a destructor in the derived class unless it's actually doing anything. 3) Use the member initializer list.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I have tried that in the `Base.h` file now, and am getting this error: `multiple definition of 'Base::Base(int, int)'`

Comment: Does your compiler support `#pragma once`?

Comment: @JohnFilleau, yes I am using `mingw` and eclipse I have made some other small projects while learning and the issues went away when I included `#pragma once`

Comment: Okay, well that would have been too easy of an answer if that was the case. Do you have a `Base.cpp` file? You've got a second `Base::Base(int, int)` *somewhere*. The trick is to figure out where. You probably are compiling `Derive.cpp` into `Derive.o`, which has a `Base(int, int)` definition. And you're probably including `Derive.h` in your main file, which is also compiling into `main.o` and has a `Base(int, int)` definition. This is a linker error in that case. The solution is to move your implementation from `Base.h` into `Base.cpp`.

Comment: No, but I have removed the constructor for `Base.h` file and removed the initializer list in the `Derive.cpp` class declaration, all of that works, but now I am getting a `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'` error

Comment: You don't have a `main` function in the code you've showed. Make a [mcve].

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have put the `main` file code in although it is separated into different files because of how I want to make the game.

Comment: `int Main::main()` is not the same thing as the program entry point `int main()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo. `virtual ~Base() = default;` is critically important, and will cause bugs if he removes the virtual declaration here

Comment: You may also be surprised to know that `int x, y, width, height = 0;` only sets `0` as the default value of `height`. `x`, `y`, and `width` will not be default set to 0.

Comment: @MooingDuck I suggested `virtual ~Base() = default;` but to not define the destructor in the derived class since it's not doing anything. I guess I don't understand your comment :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I'd misinterpreted your first comment as saying "delete the constructor".  After you replied, I worked out you meant "use `=default` instead of `{}`.  Now that I see what you meant to communicate, I agree with you.